# This questions is regarding Silat Al Rahim, maintaining ties of kinship. Please see the question below:

Tags: relationships

I had a fight with my father, left the house and moved to different location, then my father also moved to a different location. I want to patch up with him now but he does not want to keep any relation with me. It has been many years now, I do not know his address and he is not receiving my phone calls. Our relatives and his friends whom I know are not interested to involve and make us meet. So there is no way left for me to contact him. So, if anyone of us dies in this state, who is sinful?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know where he lives make dua for him u never know what the power of dua will bring you. Allah knows best.